# Angular: Call service worker push notification event from service

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

In angular I want to call the service worker push event from my custom service. Is it possible?

I added this code to my service. it's work on desktop and android but on iphone not worked

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
Notification.requestPermission(function(result) {
  if (result === 'granted') {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
      registration.showNotification('Notification with ServiceWorker');
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to call the service worker push event from your custom service in Angular. Here's a general outline of the steps you can follow:

1. Register the service worker: First, make sure you have a service
   worker registered in your Angular app. This can be done using the
   ngsw-config.json file or by manually registering the service worker
   in your main.ts file.
2. Implement the Push Notification functionality: Set up the necessary
   code to handle push notifications in your service worker file. This
   includes handling the push event and displaying the notification.
3. Create a custom service: In your Angular app, create a custom
   service where you can define the logic to trigger the push event.
   This service will communicate with the service worker and initiate
   the push notification.
4. Communicate with the service worker: To trigger the push event, you
   can use the ServiceWorkerRegistration object available in the
   browser's navigator object. You can access this object in your
   custom service and call methods like getRegistration() to retrieve
   the service worker registration and then interact with it.
5. Trigger the push event: Once you have the service worker
   registration, you can call the showNotification() method on the
   PushManager interface to trigger the push event and display the
   notification.

Remember to handle the necessary permissions and user consent for push notifications, as well as the data payload to be sent with the push notification.

Please note that the exact implementation details may vary depending on your specific use case and the version of Angular you are using, so you may need to refer to the Angular documentation and the documentation for the specific service worker library you are using for more detailed instructions.

Comment: thank you. I added the code in my service and its work on desktop and android but on iphone not work